Power a light only when 2 powered inputs
I have a 200 W, 12 V auxiliary light that I intend to mount to the rear of my car.
I only want this light to switch on when there is power going to both the tail lights (headlights are on) and the reverse lights (in reverse gear).
In other words, I need a component to work like an AND gate, only powering the LED when there are 2 live DC inputs.

I will tap into these from the trailer plug.
My question is, what component is best suited to make this work?
Is this a job for a relay? What type?

belongs at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

The question is entirely relevant to electronics. I only mentioned it's going on my car to give context. If you remove the car from the equation, the question still stands.

the choice is entirely yours ... the auto mechanics would be more familiar with the available automotive parts that are suitable for your project

Normally, I'd say you'd need 2 relays, but we can make it simpler.
First, let's look at the clean and easy solution with two relays:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This way the reverse "high beam" is only on when both reverse and normal light are on.
But wait... If RLY1 only closes when "Lights" is on. We can get rid of that entirely!

simulate this circuit
This way, the light is only on when it gets power from "Lights" and additionally "Reverse" powers the relay coil.
Just make sure that your relay can handle 16.6A at 12V and can take the vibration, humidity and all that stuff you have around a car. Your "off the shelf" electronics relays won't be able to handle that for extended periods of time.

Thanks.
I'm going to go with the 1 relay design, using a 20A Automotive Horn relay, designed to deal with the conditions it's going to endure.
This was my original assumption, but wanted to see if there was a better way to do it.

What's the light you're powering? If it's a simple low-power indication LED, you can just use an AND gate like you've mentioned. You will need to use a current limiting resistor though. You can find lots of standard AND gate parts: https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/ssab009/ssab009.pdf?ts=1721963936257
A couple additional things you will want to check are the threshold voltages for the AND inputs. You can use voltage dividers to bring them within range if needed. Also probably a good idea to add capacitors for filtering. You can power the AND gate off the light line you'll tap into anyways or a separate power supply if you have one available.

Tahmid - Hi, Thanks for answering. However, you said: "What's the light you're powering?" Please remember that on Stack Exchange, if you need to ask the OP for more info, that should be done in a comment (e.g. below the question). || In this case, you seemed to make an assumption (which is allowed), but avoid asking a question in an answer, otherwise your post might be flagged as "not an answer" if it has become a question. || However all that is moot, since the answer to your embedded question is in the original question: It's not a low-power indication LED - it's a 200 W 12 V light.

Thanks for the clarification SamGibson, apologies for missing! I'll remember for next time.

Getting back to the answer, since I clearly missed the 200W light note: for something like that you'd need something capable of handling the power. A relay would work well for this application. Just note that something like an AND gate IC is unlikely to be able to drive a relay (typically) so you might want to use a transistor to do so. An important consideration there is the freewheel diode. See more details here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html But since it's just a light, you could easily also drive it with a MOSFET straight from the AND gate.

When you think your post should read different from what it does, don't add a comment to it: Edit your post! One exception is changing a question post in a way that invalidates an existing answer - in this case, ask a new&improved question, hyperlinks welcome.

A relay is the correct thing to use in theory, and probably what you should not use yourself.
The vibrations your car is going to expose your relay to is going to make electromechanical relays die fairly quickly. I presume you're going to mount these electronics yourself in the vehicle in some place which is not specifically designed to hold electronics, so you're going to have even less control in what level of vibrations your circuit will be exposed to. Automotive relays do exist and could be fine, but it'll be difficult to be sure.
Your application is simple enough where a fully solid state solution is possible and likely preferable. Use a Mosfet with enough rating for the current you expect to need to switch on and off. 40A is probably a good minumum rating to have, and you can go higher if you are unsure what temperature will look like at the place this will live. You can use a logic level mosfet as a low side switch to keep the circuit simple.
I would also generally recommend optoisolation of the digital inputs, to make sure you don't inadvertently send the wrong voltage into the rest of the car. If you know what you're doing, this can be skipped, but if in doubt, better to be safe about it. Auto mechanics would probably be more immediately familiar with how dangerous playing around with the digital outputs you are using can be.

Good suggestions about the solid state solution. Can you provide maybe a (principal) schematic (with and without opto isolation)? I think this would help the OP a lot.

Thanks for the suggestion, however, automotive relays are plentiful in Australia, and are shipped with all sorts of auto accessories.
I am going to go with an Automotive relay and mount in the best possible way to avoid vibrations and the elements
